# Is there a way to print one string and prevent it from reprinting in a random string generator?

Tags: python

I've made a program that can print out a random row of characters for a dungeon-crawler like game and I'm wondering if I can make it to have the @ symbol print once and only once.

I have tried making it check the list of previously printed strings and making sure that if it has been printed it won't print again but that doesn't seem to be working and I'm kinda new to this. Any suggestions?

```
import random
import time
randomnumber = random.randint(6,16)
block = []
printed = []
health = 10
blocks = "\x1b[1;37;48m#"
x_axis = 1
y_axis = 1
randumplace = random.randint(0, len(block))
multiplier = random.randrange(6,35)
def build(blocks):
  for i in range (multiplier):
    block.append(blocks)
    i = random.randrange(1,75)
    if i == 4:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;31;48mM"
    elif i == 15:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;36;48m~"
    elif i == 25:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;36;48m~"
    elif i == 22:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;33;48m$"
    elif i == 1:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;37;48m#"
    elif i == 10 and "@" not in printed:
      blocks = "@"
    else:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;37;48m."
fip = build(blocks)
counter  = 1
print("# "+"# # # # # #" + " #" * (multiplier - 6))
while counter != randomnumber:
  printed.append(block)
  del block[:]
  build(blocks)
  print (*block)
  counter += 1
print ("" + "# " * (multiplier +1))
```

It should print out 5 - 15 lines of strings like "# . . . . M . . $ . . @ . . ."
but it instead prints multiple @ symbols like
"# . . . . @ M . . . @ . . # . . ."
I also want to make sure that other lines don't also print the @ symbol, and that's the reason for the "printed" list.

Comment: Why not make a random string of 14 characters that don't include the `@` character, then pick a random index and insert the `@` character at said index? Or create random string of 15 and just replace some char with `@` at some random index.

Comment: I’ve tried that and it bugs out and prints everything  on the next line when it prints an @

Comment: What is `fip` and why do you assign `build(blocks)` to `fip`, but the `build()` function doesn't return a value, and the variable `fip` is never used again?

Comment: Fip is an accident I left in because I was using it but I don’t remember what for

Answer (score 0):

A much easier approach is to create a matrix in memory, e.g.

```
maze = [[' '] * random_width for i in range(random_height)]
```

then you fill the maze as you like and only when it's complete you print it.

Comment: I’ll try that it may be an easier approach. Again I’m new to learning python so I’m trying to find out different ways to shorten stuff

Answer (score 0):

First of all, collapse your choice of blocks into a simple look-up table:

```
rand_limit = 75
block = ["\x1b[1;37;48m."] * rand_limit
block[01] = "\x1b[1;37;48m#"
block[04] = "\x1b[1;31;48mM"
block[15] = "\x1b[1;36;48m~"
block[22] = "\x1b[1;33;48m$"
block[25] = "\x1b[1;36;48m~"
```

Now you can do your entire maze as a nested list comprehension, substituting the block symbols for the random numbers:

```
maze_rows = random.randrange(6, 35)
maze_cols = random.randrange(5, 16)

maze = [ [block[random.randrange(1, rand_limit)]
             for col in range(maze_cols)]
                 for row in range(maze_rows) ]
```

Finally, pick a random row and column for your unique symbol:

```
maze[random.randrange(maze_rows][random.randrange(maze_cols]] = '@'
```

If you don't want to overwrite an existing symbol, then loop until you hit a blank spot.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved the `printed.append()` function up into the build function.

Try this:

```
import random
import time
randomnumber = random.randint(6,16)
block = []
printed = []
health = 10
blocks = "\x1b[1;37;48m#"
x_axis = 1
y_axis = 1
randumplace = random.randint(0, len(block))
multiplier = random.randrange(6,35)
def build(blocks):
  for i in range (multiplier):
    block.append(blocks)
    i = random.randrange(1,75)
    if i == 4:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;31;48mM"
    elif i == 15:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;36;48m~"
    elif i == 25:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;36;48m~"
    elif i == 22:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;33;48m$"
    elif i == 1:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;37;48m#"
    elif i == 10 and "@" not in printed:
      blocks = "@"
      printed.append("@")
    else:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;37;48m."
fip = build(blocks)
counter  = 1
print("# "+"# # # # # #" + " #" * (multiplier - 6))
while counter != randomnumber:
  del block[:]
  build(blocks)
  print (*block)
  counter += 1
print ("" + "# " * (multiplier +1))
```

Comment: Ah that does work thank you I see how that would work now but is there a way to add a position to that specific character, like an xaxis and a yaxis

Comment: what do you mean, could you give an example? @UnwantedTelemarketer

Comment: If I were to make that one move I would need it to spawn in, then with a specific input move somewhere. If I were to replace a certain block, I would need to make it have a specific variable or something so that I can replace one spot with the @. TL;DR I need to make it move and I have some ideas